# Only sync photos to icloud when plugged in?

Tags: icloud

I noticed that on icloud.com, when i add a reminder, it automatically gets sync on my phone when i turn on my wifi. Which is great and i really love that feature.

But that got me thinking, are my photos being synced too? Wouldnt that consume lots of data uploading it and also the battery?

Also, since im already here, why cant i access photos on the icloud.com website? Only on the windows explorer

Answer (score 1):

For syncing photos to iCloud, you can turn it off by going to `Settings > iCloud` and search for `Photos` and then turn off `My Photo Stream`.

If you want to access photos uploaded on iCloud, you need to turn on `iCloud Photo Library (Beta)` (in the same settings) so that it will automatically upload and store your entire library in iCloud to access photos and videos from all your devices.

Comment: Im asking about the icloud on the web version.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about iCloud we version too.